# Python pytube download playlist but in mp3 format

Tags: python, pytube

I want to download a playlist in `.mp3` format, I was looking for some information but could not find any, so I tried myself with that, but I get an error with the same problem that the `p.streams has no attribute`, anyways here is my code for that:

```
def play():
    p = Playlist(
        str(input(f"Playlist URL \n>>")))
    for video in p.streams:
        video = p.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
        print(video.title)
    play()
```

I just wanted to code that if I choice playlist, and put an `url` in that all the songs are downloaded in the same directory as the python file is, that is working but now I can't turn the `.mp4` files in `.mp3` or download it directly as a `.mp3`

The error is

```
for video in p.streams:
                 ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Playlist' object has no attribute 'streams'
```

Comment: About the AttributeError, you might want to peruse the pytube docs: https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.contrib.playlist.Playlist.video_urls

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that "streams" is an attribute of the "Youtube" class, not of the "Playlist" class.

The solution would be not to try to access that attribute:

```
for video in p:
    audio = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    print(audio.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Playlist don't directly have stream attribute. Try this :

```
from pytube import Playlist
playlist = Playlist(str(input("Enter link: "))
print('Number of videos in playlist: %s' % len(playlist.video_urls))

# Loop through all videos in the playlist and download them
for video in playlist.videos:
    stream = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    print(stream.title)
```

Comment: hello, first at all thanks for your reply, i tryed the code but i only get the music titles in my console but nothing is downloading, i dont even know why

Comment: okay nevermind i found the problem, there was no download() at the end haha, but still its mp4 just with a black screen

Answer (score -1):

#later fix all mp4:

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -f mp3 "${f%.mp4}.mp3"; done

#all is perfect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).